# Paypal Pro not working on Magento 1.2

Tags: magento-1, paypal

I am facing one problem regarding Paypal Pro transaction ...

I am using PayFlow Pro method for my website payment i have entered all the information from admin panel but when i checkout (onnepage checkout) and click on place order button after filling my credit card information it show me “User authentication failed” error message and transaction failed there i have check innoDB support in my database also and there is no special char in my password still its not happening ...

anybody please help me out with this i have been tring this from past 4 days ...  :(

Comment: Magento 1.2??? Are you kidding? :-) You should definitely consider an update...

Comment: yah I know its old version but the whole store is working fine and I don't want to update it. because of some custom plugins

Comment: There are a lot of security fixes between 1.2 and 1.7.0.2. Don't you have problems with hacks!?

Comment: There was only a couple of major bugs, and they were introduced by magento themselves in the newer releases. But 1.2 is vastly outdated, the PayPal API has evolved significantly since then.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.2 is a *pretty* old version of Magento.  I wouldn't be surprised if PayPal has sunset and/or changed the API this version of Magento used.  Also, given Magento 1.2 was an early version of the platform, chances are your system has customizations which may be interfering with PayPal. It's also possible you have a credentials problem.  Sometimes a *User authentication failed* is just a user who failed to authenticate.

The right thing to do here would be update your client's store so they're running a modern piece of software.  If that's not feasible (i.e. you don't have the expertise needed and don't wish to develop it), then your only other option is to debug and fix the PayPal API requests.

Modern versions of Magento use the following payment module for Payflow Pro.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Payflowpro.php
```

I'm not sure if that's the case for Magento 1.2.  Look for classes in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal
```

which extend `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc` or `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`.

Comment: I have to concur with Alan Storm. This was release 4-1/2 years ago and the PayPal API has changed dramatically (as well as the Magento code itself). The best course of action is to plan an upgrade immediately.